# Arabic in itext

Tags: java, itext, arabic

I am trying to print Arabic text in cell inside table (in pdf) using **Itext** with the following code

```
Font f = FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arabtype.ttf");
t.addCell(new Cell(new Phrase(name,f)));
```

Where **name** is an Arabic text
But it print **"????"** instead of the Arabic text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default encoding for `FontFactory.getFont()` (and just about everywhere else in iText) is stored in (search search) A PUBLIC STRING!  That makes life easy...  FontFactoryImp.defaultEncoding.  This is initialized to `BaseFont.WINANSI` (code page (cp) 1252 if I recall correctly).

I recommend setting it to `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`:

```
myFontFactory.getFontImp().defaultEncoding = BaseFont.IDENTITY_H
```

The *only* downside to using "Identity H" is that this forces fonts using it to be embedded subsets.  If you want to not embed a font, you may not use "Identity H".

Answer (score 8):

You can use com.itextpdf.text.pdf.languages.ArabicLigaturizer in itextpdf 5.4.2 as following:

```
LanguageProcessor al = new ArabicLigaturizer();
preface.add(new Paragraph(al.process("گزارش"), font));
```

Comment: Please do not post exact duplicate answers on multiple questions. Each answer should be tailored to address the specific needs of each question. If each question can be answered with the *exact* same text, consider flagging them as duplicates so they can be handled accordingly.